Google Cloud full account necessary for Google Apps Scripts?
I’m hoping someone can give me a steer on Google Cloud Accounts please.
On 13 July I received an automated email from the Google Team saying “Your trial will expire in 30 days. Activate your account to enable automatic billing and prevent loss of service when your trial expires or credits are used up.”
I thought I was on the free tier and I don’t remember starting this trial, however I have some scripts with an associated Google Cloud Project or two, all small scale for personal/family, non-commercial use, with no add-ons and nothing in the Marketplace.
Obviously I would prefer not to activate the full account if it results in an unnecessary expense.
How can I determine if the full account isn’t activated whether something will break? Or, alternatively, whether my scripts / projects will continue uninterrupted on the free tier?
I have looked at various Google official web pages related to Google Cloud accounts but have not been able to find the answer to this question. I have also tried asking Google Cloud sales but have not received an answer.
I was expecting that there was some scripts which didn't require a full Google Cloud full account and others which did, and that it would be easy to understand which was which and therefore whether a full account is required or not.

From the question

Google Cloud full account necessary for Google Apps Scripts?

No. New Google Apps Scripts projects are linked to what Google calls a "default" Cloud project. These projects don't require using the Cloud console / setting up a Cloud billing account.
"Unfortunately", some Advanced Services might require linking the Apps Script project to a "standard" Cloud project. Also, publishing add-ons, among other tasks, requires linking the Apps Script project to a Cloud project. This implies, for users not already having a "full" Cloud Platform account, signing up for the Cloud Cloud Platform and setting up a billing account.
To make all your scripts to use default Cloud project instead of an standard one, you might create a copy of the Apps Script projects having a standard Cloud project that you want to keetp, then delete the standard Cloud project and Apps Script project linked to it.
Resources

Google Cloud projects - Apps Script guides

Related

In layman terms: Relation between Google Apps Script and Google Cloud Platform
Free Tier in Google Cloud platform
Will I be charged if I give the credit card information but then not verify the account. (Google Cloud Platform)?


Thanks for this advice Wicket. As I don't believe I am using any Advanced Services, I'll check to see whether I can move all my scripts to my default Cloud project

@AndrewScheiner Not sure what you mean by "my defautl Cloud project". Please bear in mind that once a Apps script project is linked to a standard Cloud project, it can't be assigned to a default Cloud project, but when making a copy of a App project, the copy will be linked to a default Cloud project instead to a standard one.

Ok, got it. can't move, but can copy them. thanks Wicket
